# Hive 1.2 show schemas and show tables does not return results

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a strange behavior in Hive 1.2.1000.2.5.3.58-3 , this is the step order :

- I type "show tables", and get no results, type "show schemas" and get no results(not even default schema)
- I create a test schema test1 successfully, but if i try "show schemas" again get no results.
- I create a test table(managed) on the test schema successfully  and insert some data in it successfully , if i query the table, i get the inserted rows, if i type "describe test1.test_table" algo get the columns
- I try again "show schemas" and no results, try show tables, and can't see my test table, but i know it's there because it can be queried. (tried use test1;show tables; and show tables in test1 in all my tests)

Can this be a Metastore bug or bad configuration? if not, what else can it be? i thought a security issue, but my understanding is that if you have select rights, you should also be able to see the object(also im able to do a describe on the table) or are there special rights for "show" instruction?

Comment: Another strange finding: this behavior occurs in HUE and in Squirrel clients,when using Hive native client, i can list tables and schemas as normally

Comment: Which version of Hive?

Comment: This is it:
hive --version
Hive 1.2.1000.2.5.3.58-3